# xml-apis JAR file necessary?

Tags: java, maven, dependencies

I'm using a (Maven) dependency which itself depends on `xml-apis`. Unfortunately, the presence of this package now causes conflicts in our OSGi environment (see below in case it should be relevant).

Looking at the JAR content, I find classes which seem to be present in a current JRE anyways. So, my question: Is it safe to exclude this dependency?

In general: Is there any official documentation about classes which used to be stand alone dependencies and which have been integrated into the JRE now?

---

Here's the mentioned OSGi error when the created `xml-apis` bundle is present:

```
Bundle was not resolved because of a uses contraint violation.
  org.osgi.service.resolver.ResolutionException: Uses constraint violation. Unable to resolve resource my.company.plugin [osgi.identity; osgi.identity="my.company.plugin"; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="2.0.0.201707131542"; singleton:="true"] because it is exposed to package 'javax.xml.transform' from resources org.eclipse.osgi [osgi.identity; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="3.11.1.v20160708-1632"; osgi.identity="org.eclipse.osgi"; singleton:="true"] and xml-apis [osgi.identity; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="1.4.1.bnd-vA0Q7A"; osgi.identity="xml-apis"] via two dependency chains.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define the xml-apis as an explicit dependency in the pom.xml of your project with the scope "provided". Then it will not be part of the runtime dependencies.

Comment: Thank you, I know how to exclude them. My question targets the potential negative implications.

Comment: Since the Java XML APIs have been endorsed in Java 5 it is safe to assume they are provided. I don't think anybody is using a JDK < 1.5 anymore.